GitHub PR review suggestion including fenced code sections with triple backticks
On a PR review I was trying to add a suggestion to a markdown readme. The part of the document I'm commenting on contains fenced code sections with triple-backticks (```).
However the beginning of the fenced code-block escapes the suggestion context of the PR comment.
Is there any way to escape these? I tried \```, and ``````, but have no idea how this might work. I also couldn't find anything on SO or Googling, so I'm asking here.

You can just add an additional backtick to the suggestion block to differentiate it from the code blocks, as shown below:
````suggestion
```
Added new lines and content here, with more back-ticks ```
````

Source: https://github.com/github/markup/issues/1687#issuecomment-1836916420
